# Solve $\int (x+2)/(x^2+2)dx$

Tags: integration

How can I integrate $\int\frac{x+2}{x^2+2}dx$?

I have tried splitting the integral into two pieces and can solve $\int\frac{x}{x^2+2}dx$ by substituting $x^2+2$, but the $\int \frac{2}{x^2+2}dx$ I have problems getting.

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \tan^{-1}x$$

And to prove this, you may substitute $x = \tan \theta$ and $dx = \sec^2\theta d\theta$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write your integral in the form
$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+1}$$ and set $$t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int  \frac { x+2 }{ { x }^{ 2 }+2 } dx=\int  \frac { x }{ { x }^{ 2 }+2 } dx+2\int  \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 }+2 } dx=\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { d\left( { x }^{ 2 }+2 \right)  }{ { x }^{ 2 }+2 } +2\int  \frac { \sqrt { 2 } d\left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  }{ 2\left( { \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { \left( { x }^{ 2 }+2 \right) +\sqrt { 2 }  } \arctan { \left( \frac { x }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \right) +C } $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your integral I.
Divide it on two integrals J and K:
$$I=J+K$$
$$J=\int{\frac{xdx}{x^2+2}}$$
$$K=\int{\frac{2dx}{x^2+2}}$$
To solve the first one (J) use the substitution $x^2+2=t$ ; $ 2xdx=dt$
For the second one (K) you should try to make it in form of $\int{\frac{dx}{x^2+1}}$.
$$J=\int{\frac{\frac{dt}{2}}{t}}=\frac{1}{2}lnt=\frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+2)$$
$$K=\int{\frac{2dx}{2(1+\frac{x^2}{2})}}=\int{\frac{dx}{1+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}}$$
Now use substitution for $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}=k$ ; $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}}=dk$
$$K=\int{\frac{dk\sqrt{2}}{1+k^2}}=\sqrt{2}arctgk=\sqrt{2}arctg\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So in the end your integral I is:
$$I=J+K=\frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+2)+\sqrt{2}arctg\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$